# Performance lighting system?

Tags: lighting

What would a Performance Lighting system for a stage include? 
Please be as details as possible and if you can include the elements into basic lighting and modern stage lighting.

Comment: This is not really our bailiwick, here we do home improvement not commercial.  I'm not aware of a stage SE, but a live-theater forum would tend to have a lot more ***gaffers***, who are the people with the knowhow in that field.  It's nothing like what we do here.

Comment: You're building your own stage in your house? Why else would you be asking here on the DIY/Home-Improvement SE ... ?

Comment: I agree not our specialty. But in any case a lot more information will be needed. The width of the stage, how many curtail levels, the height of the ceiling above the stage. The distance from stage center to a spot light. There are a ton more things I can think of but you get the idea.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stage lighting is not home improvement

Comment: I'm afraid I couldn't find a more suitable sub-site...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Best book for stage lighting is written by Richard Pilbrow.

https://books.google.com/books?id=WSCVPwAACAAJ&dq=inauthor:%22Richard+Pilbrow%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT75bgrdrYAhUlmeAKHZAaCjEQ6AEIKTAA

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged across the SE ecosystem. They make us basically Google.

Comment: That's not a link only answer.   It's a book recommendation that answers the question perfectly.  The guy asked an incredibly open ended question which could only be answered with a thousand words.